# Visual Studio Code does not highlight syntax errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, c#, syntax-highlighting

I have a problem with VS code. 
Whatever I write is not treated by VS code as an error.
For example this code:

```
 itsNotWorking(1111asdasdasd asdasd)
    {
        asdasd  cx asd 22 1a}}}}}}}}}}}}&*^&*(*&^%TGB)
    }
```

Looks in code like this:

[image]

I did not change anything in the settings. After rebooting it stopped working properly. How to fix this problem?